# Pheatmap: Re-order leaves in dendogram

Tags: r, pheatmap

I have created a heatmap with a corresponding dendogram based on the hierarchical clustering, using the *pheatmap* package. Now, I want to change the order of the leaves in the dendogram. Preferably using the *optimal leaves* method. I have searched around but not found any solution on how to change the achieve this.

I would appreciate suggestions on how to change the order of the leaves, using the optimal leaves method.

Here's my example code with random data:

```
mat <- matrix(rgamma(1000, shape = 1) * 5, ncol = 50)
p <- pheatmap(mat, 
         clustering_distance_cols = "manhattan",
         cluster_cols=TRUE,
         cluster_rows=FALSE
         )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For "optimal leaf ordering" you can use `order` method from `seriation` library. `pheatmap` accepts `clustering_callback` argument. According to docs:

> **clustering_callback** callback function to modify the clustering. Is called with two parameters: original hclust object and the matrix used
>   for clustering. Must return a hclust object.

So you need to construct callback function which accepts `hclust` object and initial matrix and returns optimized `hclust` object.

Here is a code:

```
library(pheatmap)
library(seriation)

cl_cb <- function(hcl, mat){
    # Recalculate manhattan distances for reorder method
    dists <- dist(mat, method = "manhattan")

    # Perform reordering according to OLO method
    hclust_olo <- reorder(hcl, dists)
    return(hclust_olo)
}

mat <- matrix(rgamma(1000, shape = 1) * 5, ncol = 50)
p <- pheatmap(mat, 
         clustering_distance_cols = "manhattan",
         cluster_cols=TRUE,
         cluster_rows=FALSE,
         clustering_callback = cl_cb
         )
```